# Per year one maximum date row according to previous row date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table having two columns and I want to fetch data of 6 years with rules

1. The first row would be maximum date row that is available before and equals to input date (I will pass an input date)
2. From the second row till 6th row I need maximum(date row) that is earlier than previous row data selected data and there should not be 2 rows for same year i need only latest one according to the previous row but not in same year.

   ```
      declare @tbl table (id int identity, marketdate date )

      insert into @tbl (marketdate)
      values('2018-05-31'),
            ('2017-06-01'),
            ('2017-05-28'),
            ('2017-04-28'),
            ('2016-05-26'),
            ('2015-04-18'),
            ('2015-04-20'),
            ('2015-03-18'),
            ('2014-05-31'),
            ('2014-04-18'),
            ('2013-04-15')
   ```

output:

```
id  marketdate
1    2018.05.31
3    2017.05.28
5    2016.05.27
7    2015.04.20
9    2014.04.18
10   2013.04.15
```

Comment: So you want the max date that is 1  year or more prior to the previous date?

Comment: what is your rdbms?

Comment: Your 6th row does not match your rule. Looks like you need odd number rows

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza this is correct since i need maximum available data from previous row date <= 1 year

Comment: @JohnHC yes and single record for each year.

Comment: You need explain the logic of that rule. Right now I can't understand why rows are selected

Comment: `31.05.2014` is ***less*** than a year before `20.04.2015`...

Comment: Which RDBMS?  You say `tsql`, so I presume SQL Server (thought that's not necessarily correct), but which version?

Comment: @MatBailie sql server and version 2014

Comment: @MatBailie yes i got it i corrected it now.

Comment: Your comments, question and example data don't ***appear*** to be consistent with each other. If you can express your requirements in pseudocode or python or any other programming language, that might help. Or, on every row of your input explain why the row does or does not appear in your results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following recursively searches for the next date, which must be at least one year earlier than the previous date.

Your parameterised start position goes where I chose `2018-06-01`.

```
WITH
  recursiveSearch AS
(
  SELECT
    id,
    marketDate
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      yourTable.id,
      yourTable.marketDate,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY yourTable.marketDate DESC)  AS relative_position
    FROM
      yourTable
    WHERE
      yourTable.marketDate <= '2018-06-01'
  )
    search
  WHERE
    relative_position = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    id,
    marketDate
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      yourTable.id,
      yourTable.marketDate,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY yourTable.marketDate DESC)  AS relative_position
    FROM
      yourTable
    INNER JOIN
      recursiveSearch
        ON  yourTable.marketDate < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, recursiveSearch.marketDate)
  )
    search
  WHERE
    relative_position = 1
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  recursiveSearch
WHERE 
  id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  recursiveSearch.marketDate DESC
OPTION
  (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/56246/13

Comment: I agree with your aproach, but OP result doesnt match the explained logic.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - The OP's sample data has multiple issues which hasn't been clarified.  I'm working from the position the sample data is mistaken.  Until the OP clarifies it.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Please tell me exactly which mistake you are talking about in OP.

Comment: You can see in comment above. `31.05.2014 is less than a year before 20.04.2015` also take a moment to answer all those comment. Also you can comment here and tell if this answer is helpful or not. Right now we are just guessing. this would be much faster if you explain the logic you need with more detail

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Apologies. I got the mistake in question now.Please check data now i corrected it.

Comment: @priya Then this should do what you're asking for. Follow the sqlfiddle link, play with the data, and see if the results are what you want / expect.

Comment: Mat, there isnt an 1 year requirement on OP, just need to be different years. The max date of each year, but cant be the exact previous as one of the selected row. So many requirement and very unusual logic.

Comment: @juancarlosoropeza Look at the first three rows of the sample input and the first two rows of the sample output. It ***appears*** to me that `2017-06-01` was skipped for being within one year of `2018-05-31`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza query works fine but as in rule 1 of my question i need latest date data before input date for first row and then the year -1 logic would apply.This is not hapeening in your query.

Comment: Nope `'2017-06-01'` was skipped because is the first one after  `'2018-05-31'`

Comment: priya that is not what you put on your question :(

Comment: You should explain each output row and why is selected, otherwise we will here forever.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza everything is fine but for first row i need <=input date row no year-1 check should be there i am just saying this otherwise every other record is correct. I just need '2018-05-31' when i input '2018-06-01' else is fine.

Comment: @priya Are you aware this is my answer and not Juan's? And that I described why the result skips `2017-06-01`, but that you said my logic is wrong? And that my answer Does give `2018-05-31` when you start it from `2018-06-01`?  All in all, everything is not fine, until you clarify your original post Rigorously and in Detail *(as requested by multiple people)*, I'm afraid I won't want to invest any additional time trying to help you...

Comment: @MatBailie i found your answer and it worked perfectly for me. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do this with a simple order by/desc?

```
SELECT TOP 6 id, max(marketdate) FROM tbl

WHERE tbl.marketdate <= @date

GROUP BY YEAR(marketdate), id, marketdate

ORDER BY YEAR(marketdate) DESC
```

Comment: If you look at the output, a simple ORDER BY isn't going to cut it. There appears to be some logic based on the year (maximum date of previous row's date minus one year... I assume).

Comment: I see, yup. he could solve that by adding a GROUP BY YEAR(marketdate). Edited my answer to reflect...

Comment: I still don't think that's gonna do it. The output has 1 entry per year. It *seems* like it's based on *maybe* the max date for each year? I'm still confused as hell from that explanation though.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for your help but your query gives me two records from same year but i need one each year and latest one only

Answer (score 1):

Based purely on your "Output" given your sample data, I believe the following is what you are after (The max date for each distinct year of data):

```
SELECT TOP 6   
  max(marketdate),
  Year(marketDate) as marketyear
FROM @tbl
WHERE @tbl.marketdate <= getdate()
GROUP BY YEAR(marketdate)
ORDER BY YEAR(marketdate) DESC;
```

[SQLFiddle of this matching your output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1b392/6)

Comment: I need id column as well in output.

Answer (score 1):

you can use row_number if you are using sql server

```
select      top 6
            id
            , t.marketdate
from        (   select  rn = row_number() over (partition by year(marketdate)order by marketdate desc)
                        , id
                        , marketdate
                from    @tbl) as t
where       t.rn = 1
order by    t.marketdate desc
```

Comment: This seem to works perfect after reading the update on the question

Comment: @juancarlosoropeza This would give `2017-06-01` as the second row, the OP still appears to want `2017-05-28`.